# Ruby on Rails: Unit Testing non activerecord models and still load fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord

I may be missing something but I am stuck in this scenario:

I have a non activerecord model, which I want to test. I have derived its test case class from: **Test::Unit::TestCase**.

However, the test case class for the model, uses within itself, other activerecord model classes and I want to load fixtures for them. My problem is that the **fixtures** class method is available only when I subclass the test case class from **ActiveSupport::TestCase** (it is defined within **ActiveRecord::TestFixtures** which gets included in ActiveSupport::TestCase).

Any help, coz running the tests gives me the error:  undefined method "fixtures" (which is understandable) and in case I derive my test case class from ActiveSupport::TestCase it complains that there is no corresponding DB table. Also, I don't want to create a dummy table for backing my model class.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ActiveSupport::TestCase` without the class being an ActiveRecord class ([an example](https://github.com/wuputah/bigtuna/blob/master/test/unit/git_vcs_test.rb) - but this project doesn't use fixtures), so something else must be causing this. It must be something about how you are using fixtures, or your fixture configuration. Perhaps, by chance, do you have a fixture file for this non-AR model you are trying to test?

Comment: Thanks a ton! Actually, I commented out the fixtures(:all) part in the test_helper and then explicitly declared the fixtures I want to load in the non-AR model's test class and it works now. Due fixtures(:all) it was trying to connect to a corresponding DB table which was not there and hence was throwing an error.

Comment: How did you declare the fixtures that you want to load in the non-AR model's test class?

Comment: @VaibhavGumashta Yeah the fixtures(:all) was causing me issues too.  Might as well declare them explicitly in the classes I need them in.  +1 for both of you.

Comment: Anyone got reply to @barelyknown's comment?